# Is there a way to use DateAdd in a Boomi SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, date, boomi

I'm using Dell Boomi and in my DBv2 operation I have a query that adds +5 hours to a date. The query works perfectly in SSMS, but when I pass the same query in via Boomi and examine the results, the date field is just empty.

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour,5,[DateTimeStamp]) FROM someDB
```

in SSMS: 2023-09-19 13:50:08.863 (CORRECT. Time was originally 08:50:08.863)

in Boomi: (just an empty field)

Is there something special I need to do in Boomi to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

Adding an alias to the field using a DATEADD makes it show up.

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour,5,[DateTimeStamp]) as DateTimeStamp FROM someDB
```